# Mysql count ignores group by

Tags: mysql

I try to count rows from a group by result.
I want to count the number of exercise where there muscle is 1 
My problem is that the count ignores the group by.

I want to use this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM soFitTest.users_program 

where user_name = 1127 AND muscle = 1

group by exercise;
```

In my count I get 3, but when I run the query without this count I get only 1 row.

See the attached image.

[image]

Comment: what is your schema for `soFitTest.users_program`

Comment: why would you group result when you are not using any feature of it not even in select?

Comment: I want to count the number of exercise where there muscle is 1

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to count the rows, then try " count(*) ", instead of specifying "id" in count function.

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM soFitTest.users_program where user_name = 1127 AND muscle = 1;

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first query from your image is invalid according to the SQL standard:

```
SELECT *
FROM soFitTest.users_program 
WHERE user_name = 1127 AND muscle = 1
GROUP BY exercise
```

It happens that MySQL accepts it and produces a result but the values it returns are not determined. It is explained in the documentation page about [how MYSQL handles `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

The same query could produce a different result if the rows in the table are stored in a different order on the physical storage.

You should run:

```
SELECT *
FROM soFitTest.users_program 
WHERE user_name = 1127 AND muscle = 1
```

i.e. without `GROUP BY` to see what rows match the conditions, before being aggregate by `GROUP BY`.

Then, when you the add `GROUP BY` clause, put in the `SELECT` clause only:

- columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause - `exercise` for example;
- [`GROUP BY`aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) - they combine the values from all the rows in a group to produce a single value; `COUNT(*)` for example will count the number of rows in each group;
- you can add columns that are functionally-dependent on columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause; in plain English this means that if `exercise` is the `PK` of table `users_program` then you can use any other column of that table because its value is determined by the value of column `exercise`; but this is only if `exercise` is the `PK` (which is probably not the case here).

In conclusion, the query you probably want is:

```
SELECT exercise, COUNT(*)
FROM soFitTest.users_program 
WHERE user_name = 1127 AND muscle = 1
GROUP BY exercise
```

It filters the rows that have `user_name = 1127 AND muscle = 1` then makes groups out of them. Each group contains all the rows that have the same value in column `exercise`. From each group it produces a single row into the returned result set. The row contains the value of column `exercise` (which is the same for all rows in the group) and the number of rows in the group (`COUNT(*)`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get count of exercices, your query is correct:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM soFitTest.users_program where user_name = 1127 AND muscle = 1;
```

(COUNT(1) gives same result as COUNT(*) but doesn't try to retrieve all fields from DB - it's more efficient)

And if you need to get all rows with those criteria, you must skip GROUP BY:

```
SELECT * FROM soFitTest.users_program where user_name = 1127 AND muscle = 1
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` returns the number of rows. It doesn't check the values found in those rows, it doesn't care about `NULL` (or fields being `NOT NULL`). It is the same as `COUNT(1)`

Comment: That's what i meant :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(exercise)) FROM ......
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is :

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.id) FROM 

(SELECT id FROM soFitTest.users_program 

where user_name = 1127 AND muscle = 1 group by exercise) t1;
```