# mysql wildcard (%) gives different result as to when not using a wildcard

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that generates a report depending on your selection from a drop down box. The first option is 'All'. If I choose the 'All' option I get a different result than if I choose a specific option. It is the same sql statement the only difference is:

```
and service_name like 'enf%'
and service_name like '%%'
```

The first one gives me 16 results (beginning with 'enf') but the second one only gives me 13 results beginning with 'enf'. This makes no sense whatsoever!

The full statements (as echo'd) are:

```
select service_name,order_section from transcription_result where flags='Exported' and exported between '20180801000000' and '20180831235959' and service_name like 'enf%' group by order_section order by service_name, order_section ASC

select service_name,order_section from transcription_result where flags='Exported' and exported between '20180801000000' and '20180831235959' and service_name like '%%' group by order_section order by service_name, order_section ASC
```

I have tried taking the...

```
and service_name like '%%'
```

...out of the second statement but get the same incorrect result.

Database server version is 10.1.25-MariaDB - Source distribution
Apache/2.4.26 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/5.6.31 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
PHP version: 5.6.31
phpmyadmin Version information: 4.7.0, latest stable version: 4.8.3
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Schema of the table:

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`session_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`caller_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`service_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`order_section` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`variable_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`variable_value` longtext NOT NULL,
`flags` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'E- empty, R- Review',
`exported` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`transcribed` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`session_tbl_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`transcribed_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`time_taken` int(3) NOT NULL COMMENT 'in seconds',
`timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

SOLUTION

I changed the statement(s) to:

```
select distinct(order_section), service_name from transcription_result where flags='Exported' and exported between '20180801000000' and '20180831235959' and service_name like '%%' order by service_name, order_section ASC
```

Comment: can you please share your query with us. Actual query with variables

Comment: Please show your schema.

Comment: `LIKE` is not guilty. The `GROUP BY` part is incorrect. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40503679/4265352) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28672558/4265352).

Comment: @axiac probably would be helpful if you wrote an answer

Comment: @Exterminator The full statements are in the original post.

Comment: @axiac Both statements use the same 'group by' clause so that is not the issue.

Comment: @BenM Have added schema to the original post.

Comment: Have you read the answers I suggested? They explain why your query is invalid `GROUP BY` query. Both your queries return indeterminate results.

Comment: For both queries, a group created by `group by order_section` contains multiple different values in the `order_section` column. The `select service_name,order_section` part of the query is free to choose whatever value it wants for the `order_section` expression. It is invalid SQL and it works the same as [`select service_name, ANY_VALUE(order_section)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value). Remove the `GROUP BY` part of your query and check the returned rows to understand what I mean.

Comment: @axiac is right. `service_name` is not determined by the query. Use something like `max(service_name)` if you want to retain the grouping. I'll add an answer unless @axiac does...

Comment: @axiac Thanks, I removed the 'group by' and added a 'distinct' - problem solved! Solution is in original post. Thanks. Dumb question... how do I mark your comment as the right answer?

Comment: @ChrisLear feel free to add an answer no matter if there already are other answers. I don't intend to explain again why such `GROUP BY` queries are incorrect and why they apparently work (I already wrote a handful of detailed answers on this subject).

Comment: @mxlothar I'm glad it helped. You can post your solution as an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimal replication of the problem, based on the given schema:

```
INSERT INTO transcription_result
            (flags,
             exported,
             service_name,
             order_section)
VALUES      ('Exported',
             '20180805',
             'zzz12345',
             'one');

INSERT INTO transcription_result
            (flags,
             exported,
             service_name,
             order_section)
VALUES      ('Exported',
             '20180805',
             'enf12345',
             'one');

INSERT INTO transcription_result
            (flags,
             exported,
             service_name,
             order_section)
VALUES      ('Exported',
             '20180805',
             'enf12345',
             'two');

INSERT INTO transcription_result
            (flags,
             exported,
             service_name,
             order_section)
VALUES      ('Exported',
             '20180805',
             'zzz12345',
             'two');  


SELECT service_name,
       order_section
FROM   transcription_result
WHERE  flags = 'Exported'
       AND exported BETWEEN '20180801000000' AND '20180831235959'
       AND service_name LIKE 'enf%'
GROUP  BY order_section
ORDER  BY service_name,
          order_section ASC;  

+--------------+---------------+
| service_name | order_section |
+--------------+---------------+
| enf12345     | one           |
| enf12345     | two           |
+--------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

SELECT service_name,
       order_section
FROM   transcription_result
WHERE  flags = 'Exported'
       AND exported BETWEEN '20180801000000' AND '20180831235959'
       AND service_name LIKE '%%'
GROUP  BY order_section
ORDER  BY service_name,
          order_section ASC;  
+--------------+---------------+
| service_name | order_section |
+--------------+---------------+
| enf12345     | two           |
| zzz12345     | one           |
+--------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I hope this demonstrates the issue, and shows that the `group by` is the fundamental problem - because `service_name` is not determined by the query. Lots of flavours of SQL reject these queries, but MySQL allows them to run, which is both often convenient and sometimes confusing.

Using an aggregate function like `MAX(service_name)` would fix the indeterminate query problem.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the 'group by' and added a 'distinct':

```
select distinct(order_section), service_name from transcription_result where flags='Exported' and exported between '20180801000000' and '20180831235959' and service_name like '%%' order by service_name, order_section ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution. If you 'group by' all the columns you select you also get the correct result:

```
select order_section, service_name from transcription_result where flags='Exported' and exported between '20180801000000' and '20180831235959' and service_name like '%%' group by service_name,order_section order by service_name, order_section ASC
```